# Zip operator in python

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

If I use

```
l = zip((1,2), (3,4))
print(l)
```

this does not print the output , why do I have to use

```
print(list(l))
```

Also what does below code mean, it assigns data to `x` and `y` but how

```
l = zip((1,2), (3,4)) 
x, y = zip(*l)
```

Comment: Because zip returns an iterator of tuples. See [there](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)  *Zip is an iterator and follows lazy evaluation which means only evaluate when the need arises , so when you print the output of zip it shows the generator its pointing too. when you use list it starts to generate the string/output of the zip generator*

2)

```
 l = zip((1,2),(3,4)) 
    x,y = zip(*l)
```

*This is basically an example of unpacking the variables , run below code it basically unpacks the value you passed to zip*

```
l=zip([1,2],[3,4])
temp = list(l)
x,y = zip(*temp)
print(x)
print(y)
```

*Unpacking variables are not limited to zip , here is another example where you could use it , below I have a function which takes 3 inputs and I have a list with 3 values instead of manually having to pass each argument,I want to just pass the list in one go.* **Below code will fail**

```
def func_temp(x,y,z):
    print('call to function success')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    lis= [1,2,3]
    func_temp(lis)

    func_temp(lis)
TypeError: func_temp() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y' and 'z'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

*If I use unpack it will work fine , using unpack operator on lis is going to open up the three variables that are packed in list lis.*

```
def func_temp(x,y,z):
    print('call to function success')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lis= [1,2,3]
    func_temp(*lis)
```

*Here is good and short tutorial which talks about packing and unpacking in python in * [more detail](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/)

Answer (score 2):

`zip` creates an iterator, not a list of tuples. `print` only calls `__str__` on its argument, and building a string representation of an instance of `zip` does not actually consume the iterator. `list(l)` does; it extracts each value and puts it in a list. `list.__str__` then builds the string you want to display.

`zip(*l)` is an idiom used to transpose a list of sequences. If `l == [(1,3), (2,4)`, then the call `zip(*l)` is equivalent to `zip((1,3), (2,4))`, which gives you back the original list. In general, `zip(*zip(l))` is roughly equivalent to `l` itself.

Answer (score -1):

Because `zip()` function returns iterator (https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_iterators.asp).